# Using CSS to change single page background

Tags: html, css, background

Is it possible to add a line to my CSS like this:

```
.custom_bg {
    background-image:url(http://domain.tld/img.ext);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

And then on that certain page, call this some how so that the page 'knows' to listen to this line... is that possible?

Any help is appreciated. I'm fairly new to CSS.

Thanks

Comment: Live website link to the website or jsFiddle link will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You could add this manualy on page like `<style>.custom_bg { }</style>`, and leave your common `.css` file clean

Comment: When should the line be loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is make a class with a `background-image`(I guess you are already having that), and than use that class on the `body` element of that page, so for example

```
.custom_bg {
   background: url('URL_HERE');
}
```

And say you want to change the background of the contact page, you can make your HTML like this

```
<body class="custom_bg">
```

> Note: Call this class on the element you want to over ride the
>   background image, here I am assuming that you want to over ride the
>   background image for the body tag.

This will over ride the default styling, I guess you must be using a general element selector in your stylesheet like

```
body {
   background: url('URL_HERE');
}
```

So when you define the class, CSS will pick the image from the class thus by over riding the `default background image`

Comment: That's great thanks. - Just to add to this, is it possible to call it without the body tag? Thanks

Comment: You can assign a class to any element, be it a div, span, h3 or otherwise. Just keep in mind that to work well with an anchor you're going to likely want to apply display:block; to the style and a set width and height.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class to the body of that single page: `<body class="custom_bg">`. The rest of the pages will be unaffected by that style.

Answer (score 0):

as well as I understand all you should do is add this class to the  tag or any other container like this:

```
<body class="custom_bg">
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you want to specify  background for a particular page only in your application then do

```
<body class="custom_bg">
...
</body>
```

while the css will be

```
.custom_bg
{
  background: url('URL_HERE');
}
```

and if you want the background for all pages then try the following CSS

```
body {
   background: url('URL_HERE');
}
```